# undefined reference to ... in a nested class trying to declare an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, nested-class, undefined-reference

I'm trying to initialize an array called `ARRAY` inside the constructor of a class called `CLASS_A` and this array is supposed to be accessible by the nested class `CLASS_B`. I thought of making the array a template but that was when things started to get a little fuzzy with how to go about the syntax.

I'm almost certain that declaring the ARRAY static is part of the solution and maybe making the type `const int` a template like `A` so then the template would look like `template <class A, const int D>` and the declaration `A ARRAY[SIZE];`. Anyways I initially got this error compiling the code below and then I made some changes and got a different error.

This is a linker error by the way

```
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|16|undefined reference to `CLASS_A<3>::ARRAY'|
nested_class_incomplete_type.cpp|28|undefined reference to `CLASS_A<3>::ARRAY'|
```

**edit** duplicate code.

Comment: Read the answer and compare it to the site. I dare you to compile my code knowing everything in your link. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It has everything to do with it. You needed to define a static data member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only declared `ARRAY` in `CLASS_A`, you need to define it:

```
template <const int D>
int CLASS_A<D>::ARRAY[SIZE] = {};
```

BTW, your SIZE field is redundant, you don't need it, e.g:

```
template <size_t N>
class CLASS_A
{
public:
    static int ARRAY[N];
    //.....
};

template <size_t N>
int CLASS_A<N>::ARRAY[N] = {};
```

Comment: Without knowing `template <size_t N>
int CLASS_A<N>::ARRAY[N] = {};` I could've never compiled this, thanks!